# How change the tabbar layout in Komodo Edit environment? (e.g. font size)

Tags: tabs, development-environment, font-size, komodo, komodoedit

Having always many, many, many Komodo tabs open, I would appreciate to find some solution to adjust the tabbar layout. The font size for example.

Of course, in Komodo preferences I am able to change the font properties, related to the tab content. But this is NOT exactly what I am looking for.

I would like to change font properties of the TAB ITSELF in order to see more tabs on my screen without any scrolling.

AFAIK this is not possible in Komodo preferences GUI.

Is there any other solution? (e.g. editing some komodo config file)

Answer (score 1):

While waiting for a multirow tab option in future releases, my quick workaround to mitigate this issue was to declare in the 'userChrome.css' the following rules:

```
#tabbed-view tabs > tab  {
    font-size: 10px !important;
    max-width:70px !important;
}
#tabbed-view tabs > tab:hover  {
    max-width:none !important;
    background-color: #bfe0f8 !important;
}
#tabbed-view tabs > tab[selected="true"] { 
   max-width:none !important;
   font-weight: normal !important;
   color: #cc0000 !important;
}
#tabbed-view tabs > tab[selected="true"]:hover { 
   background-color: #ecbebe !important;
}
#tabbed-view .tab-text {
    margin-left: -17px !important;
}
.tab-icon {
   width: 0px !important;
   height: 0px !important;
}
```

if you're not familiar with css, basically these rules do:

- hide the icon tab image on the left so to gain a bit more space for the label-text (now positioned some pixels to the left and reduced in size).
- the width of the tabs are max 70px, except for the selected one and on mouse over. In those 2 cases it's auto.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [userChrome.css](http://community.activestate.com/faq/customizing-komodo-ui) file with a rule such as this:

```
 tabs > tab[selected="true"], tabs > tab[selected="true"]?
   { 
   font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; 
   }
```

Alternatively, use a macro:

```
 ko.views.manager.currentView.parentNode._tab.style.cssText = 'font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold';
```